# styling SVG paths in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I am new to React and I'm trying to add an svg image to my component and add dynamic styles to each of its path. However, I am having issues in doing so. I'm using create-react-app

I imported my svg as a React component

```
import { ReactComponent as SVGimg} from './img/svg-img.svg';
```

and used it on my render. I was hoping to add styles to all paths by using a for...of loop which I worked on plain HTML/CSS/JS

```
render() {
  const svgImg = document.querySelectorAll('svg path')
  for (let path of svgImg) {
    path.classList.add('some-class');
  }

  return(
    <div>
      <SVGimg/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I also want to mention that the SVG has a lot of paths

Comment: Do you mean you want to add random styles so it changes after each render of the page? Or just to add styles after load? Either way I think class names and css is the way to go. I was wondering if you wanted an iterator so pathClass1, pathClass2 etc?

Comment: I wanted to add a delay to each path after it loads.. I already have the css class but I couldnt figure out how to grab the paths from the svg.. the answer below worked :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a class to the svg say: `<svg><path class='pathClass'></svg>`

Then in your React component you can get the path by calling: `const path = document.getElementsByClassName('pathClass');`

And add the class like so: `path.classList.add('some-class');`

**UPDATE**

Since you are using a class component you could call the `classList.add()` method inside the `componentDidMont()` native React method like so:

```js
class YourComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.svgRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.svgRef.current.classList.add('some-class');
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <SVGimg ref={this.svgRef} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This will be triggered immediately after the render method finishes.

Comment: this is still not working.. when I console.log inside the for...loop, nothing gets returned, however, even path.length.. when I run path.length on the console, it returns 0.. but when I run the entire block of code in the console (const and for loop) the svg gets styled.. I'm wondering if its because of the placement of <SVGimg /> ?

Comment: The problem is that the svg element has not been added to the DOM yet you will need to use [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to be able to access DOM elements

Comment: I havent learned about react refs yet but this worked like magic! thank you so much!!